# InvalidGrantException, Invalid authorization code when running two (or more) Spring OAuth Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

Two services are there.I am using Netflix stack[Eureka/zuul].

1. AGGREGATOR-SERVICE
2. USER-SERVICE [Spring OAUTH]

when I am running one instance of user-service everything works fine but when I run another instance on another server I am getting below mentioned error and request[login oauth] gets failed.

I want to scale USER-SERVICE which uses spring oauth.

> Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Invalid authorization code:
>   Q1j7Hs 06:24:17.253 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO 
>   o.s.s.o.p.e.TokenEndpoint - Handling error: InvalidGrantException,
>   Invalid authorization code: w9uvl1

Any leads or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Configure `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` to use  `JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices` service to store and share authorization codes through database between all authentication nodes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    // JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices stores authentication codes in a database.
    @Bean
    public JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices jdbcAuthorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .authorizationCodeServices(jdbcAuthorizationCodeServices());
    }
}
```

And create [`oauth_code`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) table:

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_code (
    code VARCHAR(256), authentication LONGVARBINARY
);
```

Comment: Hello Michal, This solution didn't solve the problem for me. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two instances you must take care, that one client always talks to the same instance. Otherwise the client might make the first request to instance A and further requests to instance B.

Normaly in such a scenario the client connects to a load balancer that forwards to the instances of your service.

Than you have to options :

1. configure the load balancer to always connect a client to the same instance, thats done with sticky sessions.
2. let the instances share their sessions e.g. in a reddis store 
   see here [spring session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/)

Comment: Thank you. We have used redis because we were not able to use sticky sessions.